# Gyroscope drifting too much

Tags: filter, raspberry-pi, gyroscope, imu

I am attempting to make a quadcopter, and I am using the MPU6050 to get angle data for my PID algorithm. However, even with the complimentary filter in place, I am still getting way to much drift on the gyroscope over time, especially on the y axis. If anyone could suggest improvements to the code to minimize said drift, that would be much appreciated.

'''

```
from mpu6050 import mpu6050
import time
import math

imu = mpu6050.mpu6050(0x68)

gyro_angle_x,gyro_angle_y,gyro_angle_z = 0,0,0     
accelerometer_angle_x, accelerometer_angle_y = 0,0
comp_filtered_x,comp_filtered_y = 0,0

filter_const = 0.9
pi = 3.14159265358979323846
rad_deg = 57.29578
gyr_const = 131
acc_const = 4096.0
gyro_error_x = 0
gyro_error_y = 0

imu.set_gyro_range(250)
imu.set_accel_range(8)

dt, time_curr , time_prev = 0,0,0

time_curr = time.time()

i = 0
while i < 200:
    gyro_error_x += imu.read_i2c_word(imu.GYRO_XOUT0) / gyr_const
    gyro_error_y += imu.read_i2c_word(imu.GYRO_YOUT0) / gyr_const
    i +=1

gyro_error_x = gyro_error_x / 200
gyro_error_y = gyro_error_y / 200
while True:
    time_prev = time_curr
    time_curr = time.time()
    dt = (time_curr - time_prev)

    gyro_raw_x = (imu.read_i2c_word(imu.GYRO_XOUT0) / gyr_const) - gyro_error_x
    gyro_raw_y = (imu.read_i2c_word(imu.GYRO_YOUT0) / gyr_const) - gyro_error_y
    gyro_raw_z = imu.read_i2c_word(imu.GYRO_ZOUT0) / gyr_const

    gyro_angle_x += gyro_raw_x * dt
    gyro_angle_y += gyro_raw_y * dt
    gyro_angle_z += gyro_raw_z * dt

    accelerometer_raw_x = imu.read_i2c_word(imu.ACCEL_XOUT0) / acc_const
    accelerometer_raw_y = imu.read_i2c_word(imu.ACCEL_YOUT0) / acc_const
    accelerometer_raw_z = imu.read_i2c_word(imu.ACCEL_ZOUT0) / acc_const

    accelerometer_angle_x = math.atan((accelerometer_raw_y)/math.sqrt(pow((accelerometer_raw_x),2) + pow((accelerometer_raw_z),2)))*rad_deg
    accelerometer_angle_y = math.atan(-1*(accelerometer_raw_x)/math.sqrt(pow((accelerometer_raw_y),2) + pow((accelerometer_raw_z),2)))*rad_deg

    comp_filtered_x = (filter_const * gyro_angle_x) + ((1-filter_const) * accelerometer_angle_x)
    comp_filtered_y = (filter_const * gyro_angle_y) + ((1-filter_const) * accelerometer_angle_y)

    print(comp_filtered_x, "   ", comp_filtered_y)
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's something you can do about that. The cheap gyros in an MPU6050 are just not accurate enough to prevent drift. For reliable orientation, you will need something that at least has a magnetic sensor for absolute orientation as well, such as a BNO055.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I did that did help was change my filer constant to 0.8. I found that that gave accurate enough answers without allowing for too much gyro drift. Often on sites you'll find 0.97, but I think that is for much better quality equipment.